# Can I ever hope to be secure using a cell phone or any mobile device?

Tags: physical, nsa

I love my phone, it's small, I can bring it everywhere, I can access the wealth of human knowledge online, and do so much more. But with the recent light of the NSA and other world government agencies, the question is how secure is my phone? Can I really treat my phone like my laptop or desktop?   I also wonder how they are taking my data. Do they spoof a network and grab whatever my phone willingly puts out? Or do they hack in using a backdoor and preform a "backup" of sorts to their servers?   Is VPN or TOR enough to mask my data? What if I don't have any paid cell phone plan on this phone, does that change the methods of attack any or no?

The main question is though, can I ever hope to be secure using a cell phone or any mobile device (like a tablet) and how?

My current mobile devices, a tablet and a phone, both run the latest android operating system.

EDIT: If a cell phone is not secure, is there some mobile device that could be as secure and useful?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the NSA unless you are doing illegal things (then you have bigger things to worry about).  If that is the case, my advice is stop doing illegal things :-).  A bigger concern is hackers / identity thieves who might try to get at your data and use it for bad purposes.

Answer (score 1):

We have actually covered this topic off many times. The NSA is not really relevant here.

What is relevant is: if you are a target, then you are unlikely to be able to secure phone. If you are not a target, then why worry. Organisations like the NSA obtain a lot of data - far too much to be able to analyse it all.

Single use devices that you then discard are very difficult to trace, which is why they are used by criminals. They are especially difficult to trace if you pay for them in cash. (Or with other people's credit cards) - but I'm guessing this is not going to meet your use case requirements.

Comment: What I'm most worried is what will they do with all this data on me in the future. Sure right now it's all seemingly "legal" and mostly harmless. But can they use this data on me in some way to limit my freedoms? Can other hackers get this same data either from the NSA servers or from using the same NSA techniques to hurt me?

Comment: Of course they can. Any skilled attacker could. You are focusing on the wrong thing. We talk a lot here about threat models - you cannot protect yourself against every thing, so just focus on those things that are relevant and that you can fix. Work out what threats are relevant to you, and see what you can do. Phone hacking by the NSA is not ever going to feature in most people's threat model.

Answer (score -1):

The phone device itself is not a highly assuranced secure computing device because the chipboard is not designed not implemented for high assurance security computing. Even if you have a really strong 8192 bit RSA key stored in the phone to do your crypto, the memory is still open and so are the other sensors and access ports (USB, NFC ...). In a strict sense, the phone device is not secure in any sense.